# Criar função padLeft com keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando criar uma função em que o usuário informa um **número de 6 dígitos** + o **ano**

Por exemplo:

- Se eu digitar:    12016 => 000001/2016
- Se eu digitar:   122016 => 000012/2016
- Se eu digitar:  1232016 => 000123/2016
- Se eu digitar: 12342016 => 001234/2016

E logo em seguida tenho que colocar uma barra antes dos 4 últimos números para considerar como o **Ano**.

https://jsfiddle.net/al_unser/67o0oqn4/2/